# Postgres datetime and bigint handling

Tags: postgresql, datetime, bigint

We are a development team who have run into a strange bug in Jira. Trying to clean up the mess from the bug we want to update the dates of our springs in Jira database.

We are using Windows server and we have Postgres installed on it.

I have found the relevant table and when I write

```
select *
from "AO_60DB71_SPRINT"
```

find this:

---

Closed; Complete_Date; END_Date; ID; Name; Rapid_View_ID; Sequence; Started; Start_Date

t;1433318043661;1433226900000;1;"Sprint 1";1;;t;1432190100102
t;1433924067416;-61680144720000;2;"Sprint 2";1;;t;-61681095120000
t;1434528978422;-61679885580000;3;"Sprint 3";1;;t;-61680144780000
t;1435130684508;-61678935480000;4;"Sprint 4";1;;t;-61679540276038
t;1435735227248;-61678337460000;5;"Sprint 5";1;;t;-61679115060000
t;1436340875991;-61677749880000;6;"Sprint 6";1;;t;-61678354663584
t;1436944702756;-61677125820000;7;"Sprint 7";1;;t;-61677730634396
t;1437549239766;-61676517000000;8;"Sprint 8";1;;t;-61677121774120
t;1438154558709;-61675915920000;9;"Sprint 9";1;;t;-61676520745914
t;1438764063437;-61675313460000;10;"Sprint 10";1;;t;-61675918235812
t;1439366509383;-61674701940000;11;"Sprint 11";1;;t;-61675306752010
t;1439970303684;-61674080220000;12;"Sprint 12";1;;t;-61674703008615
f;;1440602460000;13;"Sprint 13";1;;t;1439979707567

---

The interesting fields here are the date values stored as bigints. A few of these values are positive and the others are negative.

When I look at what the dates represent by writing

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP("START_DATE" / 1000)
from "AO_60DB71_SPRINT"
```

"2015-05-21 08:35:00+02"
"0015-05-28 11:28:00+01"
"0015-06-08 11:27:00+01"
"0015-06-15 11:22:04+01"
"0015-06-20 09:29:00+01"
"0015-06-29 04:42:17+01"
"0015-07-06 10:02:46+01"
"0015-07-13 11:10:26+01"
"0015-07-20 10:07:35+01"
"0015-07-27 09:29:25+01"
"0015-08-03 11:20:48+01"
"0015-08-10 11:03:12+01"
"2015-08-19 12:21:47+02"

What I want to achieve is an update to the above column where all dates that are of the year 0015 should be update to the (bigint corresponding) year 2015.

My plan was to something like this:

```
Select
   "START_DATE",
   EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL '2000 years')*1000 + "START_DATE"
from "AO_60DB71_SPRINT"
```

But the resulting datatype of the second row is a double.

My questions in the end are

1. Is it safe to make an update where I insert the double into the bigint column?
2. If not, what's the missing step in my conversion?
3. Being totally novice to postgres, How do I make the update?
4. Do I need to make a commit afterwards?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I only have one question: **why** would anyone store a date or timestamp in an integer column?

Comment: I ask myself the same thing! I assume this is a Jira/Atlassian thing. Not sure though. We installed the products, found this oddity and fixed our problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field you are updating seems harmless so there is little risk in performing an update to this column.

You can self reference the value for `Start_Date` in an `UPDATE` query. And can also make use of the `WHERE` clause to narrow down the target rows.

Conversions are done using `::type` notation.

A query that can do what you want could look like:

```
UPDATE AO_60DB71_SPRINT
    SET Start_Date = Start_Date + (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL '2000 years')*1000)::bigint
    WHERE Start_Date < 0;
```

On success it should return `UPDATE <count>` and does not require a `COMMIT`.

Comment: I only had to do some minor modifications du to case sensitivity.
Many thanks!